# How to compute the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(-n-1+j)a+b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I encountered the following sum when computing a determinant of some matrix:

$$S(N,a,b) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} \dfrac{1}{(-n-1+j)a - b}$$

where $N$ is an odd integer, $n = \dfrac{N-1}{2}$, and $a, b$  are some complex valued constants.

Is there any chance to find this sum analytically for the most general case?
If this is not possible, the case of real $a \ll |b|$ and $N \gg 1$ might be also helpful.

Comment: Since $S(N,a,b)$ is defined as a finite sum you already have an analytic expression which is valid for all $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, but I posted an answer below with an alternate expression in terms of the harmonic number function which is expressed analytically (over the whole complex plane) as $H_n=\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(n+1)$ in terms of the Euler-Mascheroni constant and the digamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica gives the result

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{(-n-1+j)\, a-b}=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(N-n-\frac{b}{a}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-n-\frac{b}{a}\right)}{a}\tag{1}$$

in terms of the [Digamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)) and for $n=\frac{N-1}{2}$

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{N-1}{2}-1+j\right) a-b}=\frac{H_{\frac{N-1}{2}-\frac{b}{a}}-H_{-\frac{N+1}{2}-\frac{b}{a}}}{a}\tag{2}$$

in terms of the [Harmonic number function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html),

Comment: Ah, I was so naive thinking WM won't be able to give anything simple :). Well, looks like the spectrum of my operator is a transcendental equation involving digamma functions, mb will have luck estimating it in some limits.

Comment: Thank you, Steven!

Comment: Funny, but exactly this formula written somewhere in the wikipedia, and known as the difference relation for digamma function. Another fun fact: MATLAB can not compute it for negative arguments by default :). There are plenty of alternative representations, and its weird that mathworks can not make an update in 2022 on such things.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3 Here's an infinite series representation: $S(N,a,b)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{N-1}{2}-1+j\right)\, a-b}=4\, a N \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{((1-2 k)\, a+2 b)^2-a^2 N^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

For you question in comments about $$S(N,a,b)=4\, a N \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{\big[(1-2 k)\, a+2 b\big]^2-a^2 N^2}\right)$$ Using the digamma function

$$a\,S(N,a,b)=\psi \left(-\frac{b}{a}+K-\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(-\frac{b}{a}+K+\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-$$ $$\psi
   \left(-\frac{b}{a}-\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\psi
   \left(-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Expanded as series for large values of $K$
$$\color{blue}{S(N,a,b)=\frac 1 a \left(\psi\left(-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(-\frac{b}{a}-\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-}$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac N {aK} \Bigg[1+\frac{b}{a K}-\frac{a^2 \left(N^2-1\right)+12 b^2}{12 a^2 K^2} +O\left(\frac{1}{K^3}\right)\Bigg]}$$

Comment: Hello again, Claude! Nice to see you. Will check asap how well does this formula work for some realistic big $N$. Thanx!

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. Please, let me know. Cheers :-)